# stuck in this JFrame program

Tags: java, jframe

Working on this JFrame lab for my java class. My program isnt finished yet but i just need some help on why the JFrame for the male and female isnt showing after i click on the male or female JButton. any help would be appreciated.

here's my program:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Lab4EC extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
    private static final int Width = 500;
    private static final int Height = 200;

    private JLabel bodyweightJL,wristmeasurementJL,waistmeasurementJL,hipmeasurementJL,forearmJL,bodyfatJL;

    private JTextField bodyweightTF,wristmeasurementTF,waistmeasurementTF,hipmeasurementTF,forearmTF,bodyfatTF;

    private JButton maleJB,femaleJB,calculateJB,exitJB;

    double A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,a1,a2,b,B,bodyWeight,wristMeasurement,hipMeasurement,forearmMeasurement,waistMeasurement,fbodyFat,mbodyFat,fbodyFP,mbodyFP;

    Container pane = getContentPane();

    public Lab4EC ()
    {
        setTitle ("Body Fat Calculator");

        maleJB = new JButton ("Male");
        femaleJB = new JButton ("Female");

        pane.setLayout (new GridLayout (2,1));

        pane.add(maleJB);
        pane.add(femaleJB);

        maleJB.addActionListener(this);
        femaleJB.addActionListener(this);

        setSize(Width, Height);
        setVisible (true);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {

        if(e.getActionCommand().equals("Male")){


         bodyweightJL = new JLabel ("Enter Body Weight: ", SwingConstants.RIGHT);
         waistmeasurementJL = new JLabel ("Enter Waist Measurement: ", SwingConstants.RIGHT);
         bodyfatJL = new JLabel ("Your Body Fat Percentage Is: ", SwingConstants.RIGHT);

         bodyweightTF = new JTextField(10);

         waistmeasurementTF = new JTextField(10);

         calculateJB = new JButton ("Calculate");

         pane.setLayout (new GridLayout (4,2));
         pane.remove(maleJB);
         pane.remove(femaleJB);
         pane.add(bodyweightJL);
         pane.add(waistmeasurementJL);
         pane.add(bodyfatJL);
         pane.add(calculateJB);
         pane.add(bodyweightTF);
         pane.add(waistmeasurementTF);
         pane.add(bodyfatTF);

         calculateJB.addActionListener(this);
         exitJB.addActionListener(this);

         setSize(Width, Height);
         setVisible (true);

         if(e.getActionCommand().equals("Calcualate")){
             a1 = (bodyWeight*1.082)+94.42;
             a2 = waistMeasurement*4.15;
             b = a1-a2;
             mbodyFat = bodyWeight - b;
             mbodyFP = mbodyFat*100/bodyWeight;

            }

        }
        else {

         bodyweightJL = new JLabel ("Enter Body Weight: ", SwingConstants.RIGHT);
         wristmeasurementJL = new JLabel ("Enter Wrist Measurement: ", SwingConstants.RIGHT);
         waistmeasurementJL = new JLabel ("Enter Waist Measurement: ", SwingConstants.RIGHT);
         hipmeasurementJL = new JLabel ("Enter Hip Measurement: ", SwingConstants.RIGHT);
         forearmJL = new JLabel ("Enter Forearm Measurement: ", SwingConstants.RIGHT);
         bodyfatJL = new JLabel ("Your Body Fat Percentage Is: ", SwingConstants.RIGHT);

         calculateJB = new JButton ("Calculate");

         bodyweightTF = new JTextField(10);
         wristmeasurementTF = new JTextField(10);
         waistmeasurementTF = new JTextField(10);
         hipmeasurementTF = new JTextField(10);
         forearmTF = new JTextField(10);
         bodyfatTF = new JTextField(10);

         pane.setLayout (new GridLayout (7,2));
         pane.remove(maleJB);
         pane.remove(femaleJB);
         pane.add(bodyweightJL);
         pane.add(wristmeasurementJL);
         pane.add(waistmeasurementJL);
         pane.add(hipmeasurementJL);
         pane.add(forearmJL);
         pane.add(bodyfatJL);
         pane.add(bodyweightTF);
         pane.add(wristmeasurementTF);
         pane.add(waistmeasurementTF);
         pane.add(hipmeasurementTF);
         pane.add(forearmTF);
         pane.add(bodyfatTF);
         pane.add(exitJB);

         calculateJB.addActionListener(this);
         exitJB.addActionListener(this);

         setSize(Width, Height);
         setVisible (true);
        }

       }



    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        Lab4EC rectObject = new Lab4EC ();
    }

}
```

Comment: I suggest you debug your `ActionEvent e` in `actionPerformed`; maybe `System.out.println(e.getActionCommand());`. I'm thinking you don't match there. Regardless, I think I would probably register seperate `actionListeners` for the Male and Female buttons.

Answer (score 1):

I would check out [How to Use CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html).

It allows you to easily swap panels in a frame.

Answer (score 0):

Put you code in a debugger and check out lines 67 and 118.

You really need to do more of your own homework before dumping your problems here for someone else to resolve for you.

See this [link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182266/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) for some great advice.

Comment: i dont get why people in this site are like this. im just asking for someone to help so if u dont want to help then dont check out my post. its a s simple as that @mikemil

Comment: Please read the first response in the following link - it is very good advice.  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182266/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users